# Legit Math Software for Mac Users that is Free for H.S. Students

Tags: soft-question, math-software

> $\textbf{Question:}$ Is there a type of math software for $\underline{\text{Mac}}$ that is $\underline{\text{free}}$ for students that allows easy computation of functions like below? [Note the division symbol goes horizontal automatically and I can shorthand variables as numbers.]
>
> > I have found no such luck downloading math software for Mac computers, and I find calculators miserable to type in complicated functions like these. I need an alternative solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: You might want to take a look at SageMath (http://www.sagemath.org/download-mac.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desmos.com all the way. It does everything you want and more. They also have a mobile app that will sync with your account on desktop. Go check it out.